# How to automatically remove noreferrer from targetd link rel attribute, on render?

Tags: block-editor

gutenberg adds `rel="noreferrer noopener"` on every targeted link/button. I'd like to let noopener but to delete noreferrer. I know I can do it manually from the block panel. I also know of the `wp_targeted_link_rel` filter.

But I'd like it to be removed during rendering or, better, I would like to disable or alter that gutenberg functionality so that it adds only noopener.

Is there a way?